# Want to display parameters in single table from multiple lists based on common parameter

Tags: list

I have two lists which are populated by REST Response. The First list is `List<Business> Abc` and second is `List<Sales> xyz`.

1) `List<Busiess> Abc` have below parameters:

- AccountNumber
- BusinessStatus
- BusinessDescrib

2) `List<Sales> xyz` have below parameters:

- AccountNumber
- salesStatus
- salesDesc

AccountNumber is a common value in both lists.

I want to display the single table with account number and its respective parameters from both lists (BusinessStatus, BusinessDescrib, salesStatus, and salesDesc).

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read [ask], then **[edit]** your question to include anything you've tried so far, any research you've done, etc.

Comment: You can achieve this using wrapper class...

Answer (score 1):

Its better create a wrapper class which holds the data of both the objects. The list of this wrapper type can be traversed on the vfpage in a single table easily and comfortably.

Try Populating Maps From this Response 
you can useList as well but Map will reduce the system load and multiple for loops which will be required in case of different lists.

make a variable

```
public List<wrapper> businessSalesList{get;set;}
```

//-------String in the following map will be used for account number use the datatype as u wish -------

Since Account Number is common therefore the maps Can be

```
Map<String,Business> businessMap = new Map<String,Business>();
Map<String,Sales> businessMap = new Map<String,Sales>();
```

//-------------fill these maps instead of list-------------

//---------------fill the businessSalesList-----using any map's keyset

```
businessSalesList  = new List<wrapper>();
for(String str : bussinessMap.keyset()){
  businessSalesList.add(new wrapper(bussinessMap.get(str),salesMap.get(str)))
}
```

//----------wrapper class---------------Something Like This-------

```
public class wrapper{
  public Business businessObj {get;set;} 
  public Sales SalesObj {get;set;}
  public wrapper(Business buz, Sales sal){
  businessObj = buz;
  SalesObj = sal;}
}
```

//------------------on visualforce page travese this new list like-----------

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!bussinessSalesList}" var="wrap">
   <apex:column value="{!wrap.businessObj.AccountNumber}"/>
   <apex:column value="{!wrap.businessObj.BusinessStatus}"/>
   <apex:column value="{!wrap.businessObj.BusinessDescrib}"/>
   <apex:column value="{!wrap.salesObj.salesStatus}"/>
   <apex:column value="{!wrap.salesObj.salesDesc}"/>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

Do let me know if it helps..